# Display full function output's in tkinter Message widget and not partial output

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am new to **tkinter** and I am building password generator. The function is running perfectly outside tkinter algorithm.

A clear example of my actual issue: If you try to output more than one password, let's say 3 passwords, **tkinter Message widget** will only output the last one and not the 3 passwords, the rest 2 passwords are printed in terminal.

To give you pre-debug for fast troubleshooting, the main issue reside in **paStr variable** (line 61) which holds **randompassword function's output** (line 63).  The tkinter message widget is from line 153 to 162.

While it's a long code to post on stackoverflow but actually I am posting only 1/3 of the full project and exactly where my issue reside.

**Instructions:**

- Using **python 3.8**
- For **password length** please input minimum 8 for the smooth of the function.
- For **password number** or how many password, input more than 1. Input 2 or more to show up the actual issue.

**PS:** Please try the code in your computer interpreter, it is not possible to troubleshoot it using smartphone or random thoughts without trying it in interpreter.

**Thank you very much for your professional support.**

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk 
import random
import string

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("P-GEN")
width=600
height=550
screenwidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screenheight = root.winfo_screenheight()
alignstr = '%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, (screenwidth - width) / 2, (screenheight - height) / 2)
root.geometry(alignstr)
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

passLen = IntVar()
passNum = IntVar()
paStr = StringVar()


def randompassword():

    uchars = int(passLen.get() / 4)

    lchars = int(passLen.get() / 4)

    dchars = int(passLen.get() / 4)

    schars = int(passLen.get() / 4)

    str_uchars, str_lchars, str_dchars, str_schars = '', '', '', ''

    for i in range(uchars):
        str_uchars += random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_uppercase)

    for i in range(lchars):
        str_uchars += random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_lowercase)

    for i in range(dchars):
        str_uchars += random.SystemRandom().choice(string.digits)

    for i in range(schars):
        str_uchars += random.SystemRandom().choice(string.punctuation)

    random_str = str_uchars + str_lchars + str_dchars + str_schars

    random_str = ''.join(random.sample(random_str, len(random_str)))

    l = list(random_str)

    random.shuffle(l)

    result = ''.join(l)

    paStr.set(result)

    return result




def output():

  n = 0
  while n < passNum.get():
    print(randompassword())
    n=n+1


enter_chars=tk.Label(root)
ft = tkFont.Font(family='Arial',size=10)
enter_chars["font"] = ft
enter_chars["fg"] = "#333333"
enter_chars["justify"] = "left"
enter_chars["text"] = "Enter Chars Length"
enter_chars["relief"] = "groove"
enter_chars.place(x=20,y=170,width=169,height=31)

pass_length=tk.Entry(root)
pass_length["bg"] = "#d2f4d4"
pass_length["borderwidth"] = "3px"
ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
pass_length["font"] = ft
pass_length["fg"] = "#333333"
pass_length["justify"] = "center"
pass_length["text"] = "Entry"
pass_length["relief"] = "sunken"
pass_length.place(x=220,y=170,width=142,height=30)
pass_length["textvariable"] = passLen

enter_passN=tk.Label(root)
ft = tkFont.Font(family='Arial',size=10)
enter_passN["font"] = ft
enter_passN["fg"] = "#333333"
enter_passN["justify"] = "left"
enter_passN["text"] = "Enter Passwords Number"
enter_passN["relief"] = "groove"
enter_passN.place(x=20,y=240,width=169,height=31)

pass_num=tk.Entry(root)
pass_num["bg"] = "#d2f4d4"
pass_num["borderwidth"] = "3px"
ft = tkFont.Font(family='Arial',size=10)
pass_num["font"] = ft
pass_num["fg"] = "#333333"
pass_num["justify"] = "center"
pass_num["text"] = "Entry"
pass_num["relief"] = "sunken"
pass_num.place(x=220,y=240,width=142,height=30)
pass_num["textvariable"] = passNum

gen_pass=tk.Button(root)
gen_pass["activebackground"] = "#7ff14e"
gen_pass["bg"] = "#efefef"
ft = tkFont.Font(family='Arial',size=10)
gen_pass["font"] = ft
gen_pass["fg"] = "#000000"
gen_pass["justify"] = "center"
gen_pass["text"] = "Generate Passwords"
gen_pass["relief"] = "raised"
gen_pass.place(x=20,y=310,width=169,height=31)
gen_pass["command"] = output

#this is the message widget where the generated passwords will be displayed

generated_pass=tk.Message(root)
generated_pass["bg"] = "#d2f4d4"
generated_pass["borderwidth"] = "3px"
ft = tkFont.Font(family='Arial',size=10)
generated_pass["font"] = ft
generated_pass["fg"] = "#333333"
generated_pass["justify"] = "center" 
generated_pass["relief"] = "sunken"
generated_pass.place(x=220,y=310,width=346,height=192)
generated_pass["textvariable"] = paStr # paStr is the variable which holds the generated passwords from randompasword function

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move `passstr.set(result)` to above `return result`:

```
def random_pwd(uchars = 3, lchars = 3, dchars = 3, schars = 3):
..... #your same code
      passstr.set(result)
      return result
```

Code placed after `return` wont be executed, so you have to change the order of the lines a bit.
Make sure to change the last part of your code to:

```
#this is the message widget where the generated passwords will be displayed
generated_pass=tk.Text(root,bg='#d2f4d4',borderwidth=3,font=('arial',10),fg='#333333',relief='sunken')

generated_pass.place(x=220,y=310,width=346,height=192)
```

Changed from `Messagbox` to `Text` widget, and reduced the unnecessary amount of code.

Then, change your `output()` to:

```
def output():
    n = 0
    while n < passNum.get():
        print(randompassword())
        n=n+1
        generated_pass.insert('1.0',randompassword()+'\n')
```

Comment: thank you. It actually solve part of the issue, still not able to output the desired passwords number, let's say **How many passwords** input == 3 but tkinter still outputting only 1 password, any idea plz?

Comment: @CYREX How do you indent on showing the 3 passwords? I think you should ask a new Q

Comment: in tk window after you click on generate. Are u able to run the code in IDE? or do you want me to attach screenshot?

Comment: ok. gonna ask another question, you are right, i have to ask another question. hopefully you will have the kindness to help me one more time.

Comment: unfortunately I reached question limit. any help in the meantime is appreciated. thanks you again.

Comment: @CYREX Could you tell me what your looking for? like if the person says they want 2 passwords, what should be happening

Comment: in **How many passwords?** input field, type 2 or 3 or any number > 1 and click on **Generate Password** , you will have only one password, while the function is running perfectly outside Tkinter. Exactly: Tkinter is not applying **while loop** and not applying **passnum** variable.

Comment: @CYREX Yes, how long do you have your question limit, the problem is that, its basically because of the loop and you need to have a bigger entry widget? or `Text` widget

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222465/discussion-between-cyrex-and-cool-cloud).

Comment: @CYREX Once you ask a that new Q, do let me know, ive found a solution

Comment: cool-cloud answer is not wrong but the truth is I was forced to modify my question because it's the reason behind getting banned from asking questions.

Comment: You were forced to modify this Q, because you cant as a new Q?

Comment: yes bro, i was banned for no reason, if you look in my profile, there is nothing which could explain why iam banned, and it started after asking this question. anyway, please accept my apologies. actually iam outside and not in range of my laptop. I will check later. thank you very much for ur comprehension bro.

Comment: @CYREX The only reason I think why were banned could be that you asked alot of Q which has downvotes and you deleted it? So maybe un-deleting it would do the trick, nothing wrong with this Q, either ways you can also post in meta and ask them why you were banned

Comment: thanks a lot cool-cloud, you are very kind. Peace & Respect.